# Concatenating nodes in XSL and putting value into HTML "title" attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML data in a form like:

```
<Parent>
    <Child>Value1</Child>
    <Child>Value2</Child>
    <Child>Value3</Child>
    .
    .
    .
</Parent>
```

I have to set the HTML `title` attribute of the enclosing tag to the concatenated values, something like:

```
<xsl:attribute name="title">Value1,Value2,Value3,.,.,.</xsl:attribute>
```

I checked questions asked previously on SO, but most of the solutions were multiline, (and being new to XSL) I think that it i can't include the multiline code within my `<xsl:attribute></xsl:attribute>` tags. How to go about this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Parent">
  <xsl:attribute name="title">
   <xsl:for-each select="Child">
     <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I swapped the lines `<xsl:value-of select="."/>
     <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
` and the output is now fine...

Answer (score 3):

**XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Parent">
     <Parent title="{string-join(Child, ', ')}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Parent>
    <Child>Value1</Child>
    <Child>Value2</Child>
    <Child>Value3</Child>
</Parent>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Parent title="Value1, Value2, Value3"/>
```

**Or, if one wants to override the identity rule for greater flexibility**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Child[1]">
  <xsl:attribute name="title" select="string-join(../Child, ', ')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Child"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same wanted, correct result is produced again**:

```
<Parent title="Value1, Value2, Value3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="Parent">
  <xsl:attribute name="title">
   <xsl:for-each select="Child">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">, </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You copy pasted the previous solution? You could have up-voted the previous one!

Comment: if what kan wrote was `if(true)`, you wrote `if(not false)`... Makes sense?

Comment: ok suit yourself very bizarre  way to do it but yep it works fine, just think it could be slightly confusing to read

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about xsl, but there is a xpath function **string-join** which can be used may be in the xsl so that number of lines can be reduced. I usually use this function in Orbeon Xforms.

```
string-join(/Parent/Child, ',')
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp